# Django-CMS apphooked templates showing same placeholder content

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms

I've got a django-cms site on which I have created a page at `/managers-home/` with an app hook so that I can use `myapp` from that page.

`myapp` renders various templates at various URLs beneath `/managers-home/` and I would like each of these templates to have a section editable via the django-cms content plugin. Therefore I have added `{% staticplaceholder "content" site %}` to these templates, because, as I understand it, you can't use a standard `{% placeholder "" %}` from within a hooked application.

I made a start with this and added some text to the placeholder on `/managers-home/page-1/` which uses `page-1.html` and then when I got to the placeholder on `/managers-home/page-2` I could already see the content from page-1 despite now using `page-2.html` so the placeholder on these two individual templates is being shared.

How can I correctly add django-cms placeholders throughout my application templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out my problem was that a `static_placeholder` is exactly that, just a placeholder identified by the name given and anywhere you reference that name you get the same content.

So in order to allow each of my templates to display custom text, I've created a static_placeholder for each template.

```
# page-1.html
{% static_placeholder "page-1" site or %}
    Default text goes here
{% endstatic_placeholder %}

# settings.py
CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {
    'page-1': {
        'plugins': ['TextPlugin', 'UploadedPicturePlugin'],
        'text_only_plugins': ['LinkPlugin'],
        'extra_context': {"width": 640},
        'name': gettext("Content"),
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Mark, I'm facing the same problem and all of my articles in the newsblog application uses the same template. Do you know of any way to customize the content for each placeholder when I can't make a template for each article?

Comment: @Nate if you've got an app that renders the content of objects from a `News` model I'd imagine your news objects use a `PlaceholderField` so you don't need to worry about `static_placeholder`?

Comment: I had the aldryn_newsblog app so I ended up modifying site-package, which is not my ideal solution but the cleaniest